# Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $n = 1$

Tags: general-topology

I'm thinking about the Borsuk-Ulam theorem for $n = 1$. How can I show that every continuous map $f : S^{1} \to \mathbb{R}$ has some $x \in S^{1}$ such that $f(x) = f(-x)$?

My first idea was: I consider the new function $g = f(x) - f(-x)$. Let's now calculate the zero of $g$, i.e. $f(x) = f(-x)$. This equation is true when $f$ is the absolute value function. Is this the right approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Now note that if $g(-x)=-g(x)$ and use the connectedness of $S^1$.

Comment: I know that $S^{1}$ is connected, but how can I go on with this information?

Comment: @cvis: Continuous maps preserve connectedness. What are the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ are the intervals. Right?

Comment: @cvis: Yes, assuming that you are including open, closed, and half-open intervals, open and closed rays, and $\Bbb R$ itself. Of course $S^1$ is also compact, and compactness is preserved by continuous maps, so $g[S^1]$ actually has to be a closed interval.

Comment: Now I see the point. Thanks for your support

Comment: @cvis: You’re welcome.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Isn't using the fact that "Continuous maps preserve connectedness and compactness" is just a prove of intermediate value theorem?